# Switch statements aren't recognized

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I try to read the cases of a simple radiogroup. So instead of showing the selected value via toast (like in a working example), I want so sum the "score" depending on the selected radiobutton.

So the code lines in this area (MainActivity.java) that I tried:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  int selected_id = radio_group_question1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
  radio_button_question1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(selected_id);
  switch(radio_group_question1.getId()) {
    case R.id.radio_q1_answer1:
    score = score + 0;
    break;
    case R.id.radio_q1_answer2:
    score = score + 1;
    break;
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Unfortunately the "score" is always "0" like I initialized in the beginning (int score = 0;). :(

Any ideas?

Many thanks and greetings!

Comment: why don't you print a simple message inside the switch and ensure that it's actually going inside or not? that way we can narrow down the problem?

Comment: Note also that with answer 1, you are adding 0 to the score, which will leave it unchanged.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw thank you, it doesn't go inside so I think my way with the cases is wrong... looks it right to you?

Comment: @TedHopp thank you, I know but even I add 100 it doesn't change something.

Comment: @Bazi see the suggested answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `switch` statement you are checking for `radio_group_question1.getId()` which is the id of the whole radio group, what you should do is this:

```
switch(selected_id){
```